# Parsing from a json file in webdriver.io w/mocha isn't working as intended because the dragEvents do not actually drag the parsed names

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

What I can't seem to figure out is why I keep getting an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find') while trying to parse a json file. The parsing will pull in x number of fields starting with "before": "title": "- STFC42" which will be dragged and dropped over to a specific element (State 0), then expect that element to read from the "after": "details" which is "STFC42" section of the json file. I've tried so many different ways to get it to parse and then drag. I can use dragEvents just fine when I don't try to parse. So at least I know this works on my page object page:

```
import { code as dragAndDrop } from 'html-dnd'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Below I have the json snippet, my page object snippet, and the test.

**Test file:**

```
import { parseEventMapFile } from '../utils/stfc.utils'

it('should drag all items from Events to State', async () => {
    const eventMapFilePath = '../noddi/test/utils/Event_map.json';
    const sectionName = 'Fmt:0 - 3DHUD';

    try {
        const EventTriggers = await parseEventMapFile(eventMapFilePath, sectionName);

        for (const item of EventTriggers) {
            // Now 'item' contains the text you want to use for drag-and-drop
            const draggedItems = await TriggerPage.dragEvents(item.before.title);
            
            // Add your assertions here using Mocha's assert functions
            for (const draggedItem of draggedItems) {
                assert.strictEqual(draggedItem.itemName, item.before.title);
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors here
        console.error('Error in parsing test:', error);
        throw error;
    }
  });
```

**This is the page object on my class file**

```
/** 
   * Returns the element to be dragged based on the item name
   * @param {string} itemName - The name of the item to be dragged
   * @returns {Promise<WebdriverIO.Element>}
   */
  public async getDraggedElement(itemName: string): Promise<WebdriverIO.Element> {
    return this.$(`//span[contains(@class, "event-key") and contains(text(), "${itemName}")]`)
  }

  /**
   * Returns the target element (State 0)
   * @returns {Promise<WebdriverIO.Element>}
   */
  public async getTargetElement(): Promise<WebdriverIO.Element> {
    return this.$('#State\\ 0')
  }

  /**
   * Drags the specified item from Events over to the State 0 element
   * @param {string} [itemName] - The name of the item to be dragged (optional)
   * @returns {Promise<{ itemName: string; html: string }[]>|Promise<void>}
   */
  public async dragEvents(itemName?: string): Promise<{ itemName: string; html: string }[]> {
    try {
        if (itemName) {
            const elem = await this.getDraggedElement(itemName);
            console.log(itemName);
            const target = await this.getTargetElement();
            await browser.executeScript(dragAndDrop, [elem, target]);
        }

        const elements = await $$('.detail');
        await Promise.all(elements.map(element => element.waitForDisplayed()));

        const draggedItems = [];
        console.log('Elements:', elements);

        if (elements) {
            for (const element of elements) {
                const html = await element.getHTML();
                const itemName = await element.getText();
                draggedItems.push({ itemName, html });
            }
        } else {
            console.error('No elements found.');
        }

        return draggedItems;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during dragEvents:', error);
        throw error;
    }
  }
```

**stfc.utils file**

```
    import { promises as fsPromises } from 'fs';

    export async function parseEventMapFile(filePath: string, sectionName?: string) {
  try {
      const content = await fsPromises.readFile(filePath, 'utf8');
      console.log('File Content:', content); // Log the content read from the file
      const eventMap = JSON.parse(content);
      console.log('Parsed Event Map:', eventMap); // Log the parsed JSON object

      const section = eventMap.children.find(child => child.title === sectionName);
      console.log(section)

      if (!section) {
          throw new Error(`Section "${sectionName}" not found in Event_map.json`);
      }

      return section.children;
  } catch (error) {
      // Handle any errors here
      console.error('Error reading the file:', error);
      throw error;
  }
}
```

**json snippet with just 2 (I have a lot to parse):**

```
[
    {
      "title": "STFC - Ships",
      "children": [
        {
          "title": "42:Stars - 3DHUD",
          "children": [
            {
              "before": { "title": "- STFC42", "description": "Station 42" },
              "after": { "title": "Neutral Zone", "detail": "STFC42" }
            },
            {
              "before": { "title": "- Cube9", "description": "The Borg" },
              "after": { "title": "Delta9", "detail": "Cube.9" }
            }
          ]
        },
```

**I was able to add a console.log in my export section and so it does show that my objects from parsing "should" be working.**

```
[0-0] Parsed Event Map: [
[0-0]   {
[0-0]     title: 'STFC - Ships',
[0-0]     children: [ [Object], [Object] ]
[0-0]   },
```